# "I made it my prime objective settling the matter." - unacceptable extraposition

Tags: extraposition

Just saw this sentence marked as unacceptable in Quirke's Comprehensive Grammar (18.35 Extraposition of a clausal object):

> *I made it my prime objective settling the matter

The full bit:

[image]

I don't understand why this construction was deemed unacceptable. What's so different between it and 'I made it my objective to settle the matter' ? Both 'to settle...' and 'settling...' are clausal objects, no? And it says right there that -ing clauses can undergo extraposition. No further explanation is given in the chapter, so I'm a bit confused here. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: I think your confusion is resonable. I can't see that that excerpt justifies marking the last sentence as unacceptable (though I agree that it is unacceptable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I made {something} my objective.
```

I made {climbing the mountain} my objective.

Extraposed:

I made {it} my objective {to climb the mountain}.

I would say that we don't use a participle clause as extraposed object because the participle clause can act as a modifier of the main clause:

> I made it my objective walking the dog.

That could be understood to mean *[while] walking the dog*, not that walking the dog was your objective.

> I made it my prime objective {settling the matter}

could be understood to mean,  *[thus] settling the matter.*

Those meanings interfere with parsing that takes the participle clause as an extraposed object.

Comment: Thought it would be something like this. Thanks again.